# Echo the list of process not running

Tags: shell-script, shell, grep, aix

I have developed a script, the script refers to a file to start the required processes on that server. The script times out after 180 secs. At the end of the script I would like to display the processes which have not started within time frame of 180 secs. How do I achieve this ?

Reference file `ref.txt`:

```
#TEST:process1
#TEST:process2
TEST:Process3
TEST:process4
TEST:process5
```

The commands line used in the script to start the required processes is,

```
grep "TEST:" /products/test/ref.txt | while read LINE (Selects process3,4,5 to start)
do
PROC_NAME=$(echo ${LINE} | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')
echo "Starting the required process"
echo "<command line to start the processes>"
done 

#Giving script 180 seconds to start the processes

(( START_TIME = 0 ))
until [ ${START_TIME} -gt 180 ]
do 
greps for the processes running
echo " N number of processes are running"
<I want to display the processes which have not started here>
done
```

Scripts times out after 180 seconds.

I need to add a logic to display the processes which haven't started after 180 secs, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a shell like `bash` or `ksh`:

```
max_time=3

SECONDS=0

IFS=$'\n:'

grep -v '^#' ref.txt |
while read tag cmd; do
    if (( SECONDS < max_time )); then
        echo "starting '$cmd' (tag is '$tag')"
        sleep 2 # for simulation purposes
    else
        echo "did not have time to start '$cmd' (tag is '$tag')"
    fi
done
```

This will give the following output:

```
$ ksh script.sh
starting 'Process3' (tag is 'TEST')
starting 'process4' (tag is 'TEST')
did not have time to start 'process5' (tag is 'TEST')
```

The script picks out all lines from the `ref.txt` file that are not commented out and splits them on `:` to separate the initial tag from the command.

If the script hasn't yet timed out, it starts the currently read process (simulated with a `sleep` call here).

If it has used too much time, it won't start more processes but will report the ones not yet started.

The timeout will not happen asynchronously, i.e. the script won't interrupt the starting of a process if more than `max_time` seconds has elapsed.

The `SECONDS` variable contains the number of seconds since the shell was started, or, as in this case, since it was last set to zero.

Answer (score 1):

logic to display the processes which haven't started after 180 secs.
Assuming the shell is a bourne shell. I testing on `bash` and `zsh`

```
# ...

# generate a timestamp in seconds since UNIX epoch
START_TIME=$(date '+%s')
until [[ $(date +%s) -gt $((START_TIME + 180)) ]]
do 
    # greps for the processes running
    echo " N number of processes are running"
    #<I want to display the processes which have not started here>
done

# ...
```